# Make fully visible one element from overflow:hidden element

Tags: html, css

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/mtN6R/9/

```
.tooltip{
    color:red;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50px;
    position:relative;
}


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='tooltip'>A big tooltip which should be visible fully</div>
     A lot of text<br> 
          A lot of text<br>      
</div>
```

I need .tooltip make fully visible but I can't take it outside wrapper. Can we stylize that example so .tooltip will be shown above wrapper and the rest content will stay as is?

Comment: If you need to add more information to your question, just edit this one. There's no need to delete and repost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to have just your content itself have `overflow: hidden` on it:

CSS:

```
.tooltip{
    color:red;
}
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.inner {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='tooltip'>A big tooltip which should be visible fully</div>
    <div class="inner">
        A lot of text<br>
        A lot of text<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, give tooltip an absolute position and then move things around as needed as in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mtN6R/6/)**

```
.tooltip{
    color:red;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}​
```

Comment: Oh I am sorry I forgot to mention main thing on it, .wrapper is relative, I just updated please check. Sorry!