# Selective overflow: auto

Tags: html, css, overflow

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/that0th3rGuy/hGL9E/) refers.

I'm looking for a way to make the dropdown visible while keeping the information hidden. ***Edit***: Not hidden, but clipped and scrolling

To make the information hidden, **green** has `overflow: auto` but that also hides the dropdown. Alternatively, when **green** has `overflow: visible` the dropdown displays correctly, but the content is not hidden. Also, the `max-height: 150px` is necessary because I have limited space and I don't want the **red** or the page to scroll; scrolling should be limited to **green**.

I checked some other questions on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553197/make-fully-visible-one-element-from-overflowhidden-element) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367060/setting-overflowhidden-only-for-certain-elements) but they didn't solve my problem exactly, but I agree with the solutions provided there; I think my situation is a little different from those. Google also didn't provide any solutions.

PS: I always wanted to try the `:first-letter` pseudo class, but never has a use for it, so I thought I'd put it here.

Comment: i am having the same problem. Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution for your problem would be to make the content transparent so it's not directly visible. Like in css: `color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Make the content of the dropdown transparent? Maybe alter the fiddle and post the link.